# MySQL SUM function Multiplies result by number of rows

Tags: mysql

Relatively inexperienced with SQL Queries other than Selecting information from multiple tables etc without any built in workings... I'm building a website where admin can enter and track projects - This includes initially adding a project (reference/name and project value), then they can add expenses against that project. Other site users / employees can also fill out timesheets and allocate their hours/pay against that job (selected from a dropdown populated from the projects table)

I'm currently building a page where admin can track the profit/loss of a job. This shows the Job details, expenses total, labour total and profit/loss figure - trying to get all the information in one hit from MySQL rather than getting all rows and manipulating it later with php/js.

I have the following tables:

projects table

| id | customer | job_reference | value | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cust A | Job A | 1000 | 2023-11-10 |
| 2 | Cust B | Job A | 1500 | 2023-11-10 |

expenses table

| project_id | exp_amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 250 |
| 1 | 250 |

timesheets table

| project_id | project_ref | pay_total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Job A | 100.00 |
| 1 | Job A | 100.00 |
| 1 | Job A | 0.00 |

The SQL Query

```
SELECT 
    MIN(p.id) AS Pro_ID,
    MAX(p.customer) AS Pro_Customer,
    MAX(p.job_reference) AS Pro_Ref,
    MAX(p.value) AS Pro_Value,
    MAX(p.end_date) AS Pro_End,
    SUM(e.exp_amount) AS expense,
    SUM(t.pay_total) AS LabourPaid,
    COALESCE(SUM(t.pay_total), 0) AS LabourCostings,
    ROUND(SUM(IFNULL(t.pay_total, 0)), 2) AS LabourCosts,
    IFNULL(SUM(t.pay_total), 0) AS LabourCost,
    ROUND(MAX(p.value) - (SUM(IFNULL(e.exp_amount, 0))),
            2) AS Profit
FROM
    projects p
        JOIN
    expenses e ON e.project_id = p.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    timesheets t ON t.project_id = p.id
        AND t.project_ref = p.job_reference
GROUP BY p.end_date
ORDER BY p.end_date ASC
```

The Issues I'm facing are:

1 - if no timesheet information is entered for a project then the project doesn't appear at all

2 - the expenses and labour costs are all over the place - they seem to be getting multiplied by the number of rows or results but not necessarily the number of results relating to that line.

I have tried the calculations in the middle of the query, also different JOINS.

I would expect the results for project with id = 1 to be

| id | Pro_Customer | Pro_Ref | Pro_Value | Pro_End | expense | 'Any Labour Calculation' | Profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cust A | Job A | 1000 | 2023-11-10 | 500 | 200 | 300 |

I feel like I'm way off with my query - I have read about sub queries but do not understand it fully after several attempts - is this even the correct way forward ? Am I asking to much from 1 single query ? or am I along the right lines ? I've search on here and other sites and can't seem to find anything that points me in the right direction.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You create multiple lines, where the columns 0of left side are repeated.

One way would to calculate the project costs and gain before joining

```
SELECT 
    MIN(p.id) AS Pro_ID,
    MAX(p.customer) AS Pro_Customer,
    MAX(p.job_reference) AS Pro_Ref,
    MAX(p.value) AS Pro_Value,
    MAX(p.end_date) AS Pro_End,
    SUM(e.exp_amount) AS expense,
    SUM(t.pay_total) AS LabourPaid,
    COALESCE(SUM(t.pay_total), 0) AS LabourCostings,
    ROUND(SUM(IFNULL(t.pay_total, 0)), 2) AS LabourCosts,
    IFNULL(SUM(t.pay_total), 0) AS LabourCost,
    ROUND(MAX(p.value) - (SUM(IFNULL(e.exp_amount, 0))),
            2) AS Profit
FROM
    projects p
        JOIN
    (SELECT project_id, SUM(exp_amount) exp_amount FROM  expenses  GROUP BY project_id) e ON e.project_id = p.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT project_id,MAX(project_ref) project_ref, SUM(pay_total) pay_total FROM timesheets GROUP BY project_id) t ON t.project_id = p.id
        AND t.project_ref = p.job_reference
GROUP BY p.end_date
ORDER BY p.end_date ASC
```

| Pro_ID | Pro_Customer | Pro_Ref | Pro_Value | Pro_End | expense | LabourPaid | LabourCostings | LabourCosts | LabourCost | Profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cust A | Job A | 1000 | 2023-11-10 | 500 | 200 | 200 | 200 | 200 | 500 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cZIxsoMk)